# How to modify Spring Boot bootRepackage jar file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I want to modify application.properties of a jar file after build a spring boot application.
I had used `jar xf` to extract the jar file then modified the properties file but after jar-ed ( `jar -0cf` ), it had not been working with printout:

**no main manifest attribute, in < filename >.jar**

So is there anyway to do it and how?

Comment: shouldn't it be jar -cvf jarname files

Comment: i meant i've jar-ed all, but after run java -jar filename.jar it didn't work

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying anything after the artifact has been build... That would basically mean you deploy something that is untested. Why do you even need to modify the `application.properties` after packaging. Looks like you are trying to solve something in the wrong way.

Comment: isn't the jar file supposed to be copied to lib folder , so that app server can recognize it? if we are talking about Spring Boot

Comment: @M.Deinum Packaging my project takes time and i just want to modify a line in a resource file which is packaged. If i can extract jar file, modify resource files then re-packaged, that might be more faster instead of rebuilding the project

Comment: You shouldn't be rebuilding the project as much as you shouldn't be modifying it after packaging. If you have configuration differences put them in a different property file or override it for that environment. Never build different packages for different environments, as that basically means you are putting something untested into your production environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jar file is just an zip file. You can open it and add file using any of tools that manipulate zip files.

Or if you want to update using jar command line you can do it using this syntax.

`jar uf jar-file input-file(s)`

Like described here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Comment: Thanks. It worked only case i update with -uf option. Other cases fail: with winrar, zip, or even jar -0cf

Answer (score 0):

**Another Solution:**

You can override the application.properties by the **`--spring.config.location`** as the below:

```
java -jar /path-to-jar-file/jarFileName.jar --spring.config.location=/path-to-propertiesFile/application.properties
```

This way you can easily update the application.properties.
It is useful when you want to run your jar file with java -jar command line (for example run jar file as a service in the Linux).